# Good way to unit test Retrofit interface declaration

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit

I have next interface declaration:

```
public interface FundaService
{
    @GET( "/feeds/Aanbod.svc/json/{key}" )
    Observable<JsonResponse> queryData( @Path( "key" ) String key, @Query("type" ) String type, @Query( "zo" ) String search, @Query( "page" ) int page, @Query( "pagesize" ) int pageSize );
}
```

That I use after with `Retrofit`. What would be an elegant way of testing that I didn't make mistakes in URL declaration and query parameters?

I see that I can mock web layer and check urls with parameters.

**UPDATE**

I modified it:

```
public interface FundaService
{

    String KEY_PATH_PARAM = "key";
    String FEED_PATH = "/feeds/Aanbod.svc/json/{" + KEY_PATH_PARAM + "}";
    String TYPE_QUERY_PARAM = "type";
    String SEARCH_QUERY_PARAM = "zo";
    String PAGE_QUERY_PARAM = "page";
    String PAGESIZE_QUERY_PARAM = "pagesize";

    @GET( FEED_PATH )
    Observable<JsonResponse> queryData( @Path( KEY_PATH_PARAM ) String key, @Query( TYPE_QUERY_PARAM ) String type,
                                        @Query( SEARCH_QUERY_PARAM ) String search, @Query( PAGE_QUERY_PARAM ) int page,
                                        @Query( PAGESIZE_QUERY_PARAM ) int pageSize );
}
```

And partially testing it, like:

```
public class FundaServiceTest
{
    @Test
    public void PathKeyIsCorrect()
        throws Exception
    {
        assertThat( FundaService.KEY_PATH_PARAM ).isEqualTo( "key" );
    }

    @Test
    public void FeedPathIsCorrect()
        throws Exception
    {
        assertThat( FundaService.FEED_PATH ).isEqualTo( "/feeds/Aanbod.svc/json/{key}" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an okhttp interceptor to inspect the final request built by retrofit without using a mock http server.  It gives you a chance to inspect the request a bit earlier.  Suppose we want to test the following interface -

```
public interface AwesomeApi {
  @GET("/cool/stuff")
  Call<Void> getCoolStuff(@Query(("id"))String id);
}
```

The first test runs 'validateEagerly` to do a validation of the entire interface.  Useful to have in case your other test cases don't touch all the interface methods.  The second test is an example of how you might verify a specific call is generating the expected url.

```
public class AwesomeApiTest {

  @Test
  public void testValidInterface() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.example.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        // Will throw an exception if interface is not valid
        .validateEagerly()
        .build();
    retrofit.create(AwesomeApi.class);
  }

  @Test(expected = NotImplementedException.class)
  public void testCoolStuffRequest() throws Exception {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
      @Override
      public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request request = chain.request();
        // Grab the request from the chain, and test away
        assertEquals("HTTP methods should match", "GET", request.method());
        HttpUrl url = request.httpUrl();
        // Test First query parameter
        assertEquals("first query paramter", "id", url.queryParameterName(0));
        // Or, the whole url at once --
        assertEquals("url ", "http://www.example.com/cool/stuff?id=123", url.toString());
        // The following just ends the test with an expected exception.
        // You could construct a valid Response and return that instead
        // Do not return chain.proceed(), because then your unit test may become
        // subject to the whims of the network
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
    });
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.example.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
    AwesomeApi awesomeApi = retrofit.create(AwesomeApi.class);
    awesomeApi.getCoolStuff("123").execute();;
  }
}
```

I got this idea from browsing retrofit's own tests.  Other people's tests are often great inspiration!

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try today and will accept the answer